# MSSQL Script Using ?' in string

Tags: sql-server, apostrophe

I have a MSSQL script that won't work:

```
IF object_id('amClearString') IS NULL
    exec('CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[amClearString](@Text ntext)  
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sClearText NVARCHAR(4000)
    SET @sClearText = (SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(4000), @Text), '''', '?''')
                    )
    RETURN(@sClearText);
END
')
```

The problem is that it won't recognize ?' as a valid syntax.

The first one '''' works as its supposed by simply using 2 apostrophes instead of the one. But it wont work in combination with the question mark. 
Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Try to use `,''?''`)

Comment: You also should stop using (n)text. It has been deprecated since sql 2005 in favor of (n)varchar(max). What I really don't understand here is why you are creating a function with dynamic sql??

Comment: Also you are not replacing anything. This '''' becomes '' - empty string.

Comment: Do you really need a function to do this

Answer (score 1):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('amClearString') IS NULL
    EXEC('
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.amClearString(@Text NVARCHAR(MAX))  
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
    WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
    AS
    BEGIN

        RETURN REPLACE(@Text, '''', ''?'')

    END')
```

Comment: If I use your suggestion the result is

Comment: If I use your suggestion the result is

`SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[amClearString](@Text ntext)  
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @sClearText NVARCHAR(4000)
    SET @sClearText =(SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(4000), @Text), '', '?')
                    )
    RETURN(@sClearText);
END`

The problem is that I dont want '' and '?' as result.
Instead I need '''' and ''?'' as the result but as soon as I add more apostrophes to the script it results in an error